# SQL query to find out experience of employee in the format 'yy years mm months dd days'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a query to find out experience of employee in the format 'yy years mm months dd days'.

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME, DEPARTMENT, DESIGNATION, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOJ, GETDATE()) AS EXPERIENCE, 
       EMPSTATUS AS JOB_STATUS 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

DOJ - field in db for saving 'date of joining' of employee. 
This is the query which returns experience in years only. How to modify it?

Comment: Please edit your question to add a tag for the database you use (guessing `sql-server`).

Comment: what is the actual name of the field you are showing as experience in your Employee table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    EMPID, EMPNAME, DEPARTMENT, DESIGNATION, 

    convert(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOJ, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
    convert(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOJ, GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' months' 
    AS EXPERIENCE, 

    EMPSTATUS AS JOB_STATUS 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider  Emp_joiningDate  as  column

SELECT DATEDIFF(year, Emp_joiningDate, GETDATE()) AS Years,

```
   DATEDIFF(month, Emp_joiningDate, GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(year, '1/2/1999', GETDATE()) * 12 AS Months,

    DATEDIFF(day, Emp_joiningDate, getdate())- DATEDIFF(month, '1/2/1999', 

            GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(year, '1/2/1999', GETDATE()) * 365 as Days
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45bb5/3/0) for testing

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME, DEPARTMENT, DESIGNATION,
       cast(floor(experience / 365) as varchar) + ' years ' +
       cast(floor(experience % 365 / 30) as varchar) + ' months ' +
       cast(experience % 30 as varchar) + ' days' as experience,
       EMPSTATUS AS JOB_STATUS 
FROM (select *, datediff(DAY, doj, getdate()) as experience
      from employee) t
```

Comment: i am getting an error like 'CONCAT' is not a recognized function name. i am using SQL Server 2008 , sorry i didn't mention it in my question.

Comment: @sanuj Updated answer and SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2013-12-01 23:59:59.000', 
        @ToDate   DATETIME = '2016-08-30 00:00:00.000',
         DECLARE @MONTHS INT

        SET @Months = DATEDIFF(MM,@FROMDATE,@TODATE)


        IF (DATEPART(MM,@FromDate) <=  (DATEPART(MM,@TODATE))+1)
            BEGIN
                    SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(YY,@FROMDATE,@TODATE) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' Years '+ CAST( (DATEPART(MM,@TODATE)-DATEPART(MM,@FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(5))+1 +' Month'
            END 
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                    SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(YY,@FROMDATE,@TODATE)-1 AS VARCHAR(5)) +' Years '+ CAST(12-(DATEPART(MM,@FROMDATE)) + DATEPART(MM,@TODATE)+1  AS VARCHAR(5) ) +' Month'
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getEmployePeriod]
    (
      @dateofbirth DATETIME
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @currentdatetime DATETIME;
        DECLARE @years INT;
        DECLARE @months INT;
        DECLARE @days INT;
        DECLARE @currentMonthdays INT;
        DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100);
        SET @currentdatetime = GETDATE();--current datetime

```
    IF ( @dateofbirth <= GETDATE() )
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dateofbirth, @currentdatetime); -- To find Years
            SELECT  @months = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @dateofbirth,
                                       @currentdatetime) - ( DATEDIFF(YEAR,
                                                          @dateofbirth,
                                                          @currentdatetime)
                                                          * 12 );
            SELECT  @days = DATEPART(d, @currentdatetime) - DATEPART(d,
                                                          @dateofbirth);-- To Find Days
            SELECT  @currentMonthdays = ( SELECT    DAY(DATEADD(DD, -1,
                                                          DATEADD(mm,
                                                          DATEDIFF(mm, 0,
                                                          GETDATE()), 0)))
                                        );
            IF ( @months < 0 )
                BEGIN
                    SET @months = 12 + @months;
                    SET @years = @years - 1;
                END;
            IF ( @days < 0 )
                BEGIN
                    SET @days = @currentMonthdays + @days;
                     IF(@months<>0)
                    begin
                    SET @months = @months - 1;
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    SET @years = @years - 1;
                    SET @months = 11;
                    end
                END;
```

-- To Find Months

```
            SET @result = CAST(@years AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' years,   '
                + CAST(@months AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' months,   '
                + CAST(@days AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' days'; 

        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @result = 'Invaild date of birth';
        END;
    RETURN @result;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-01-01', GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
    convert(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(DD, '2016-09-21', GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' months' 
    AS EXPERIENCE
```